# Reusable Model Formatting in Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, formatting

How can I format the presentation of a model inside a view any way I want?
being able to implement custom formatters that I can reuse.

For example - I have a `Model.Name` which has the value of "david kim" and i want to capitalize the first letters. So, instead of showing the actual name - "**david kim**", it will display "**David Kim**" instead.

More examples:

Removing numbers from strings: **helloworld123 -> hellowworld**.

Converting text to leet speech: **Hello world -> H3110 w0r1d**.

by using something as easy as that:

```
// Here I use the Capital Letter custom formatter.
@Html.DisplayFormatFor(model => model.Address, new CapitalLetterFormatter())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation for model formatting as an elegant reusable code.

There is an `HtmlStringFormatter.Create()` which allow you to pass a delegate and make your own anonymous formatter.

**Code Sample:**

```
// This just upper case all the letters.
@Html.DisplayFormatFor(model => model.Address, HtmlStringFormatter.Create(s=> s.ToUpper()))
```

If You to create a custom formatter, derive from `HtmlStringFormatter` and set its delegate property to whatever manipulation you want to do.

**Code Sample:**

```
// Here I use the Capital Letter custom formatter.
@Html.DisplayFormatFor(model => model.Address, new CapitalLetterFormatter())
```

**All the classes:**

```
namespace MvcPlay.HelperExtensions
{
    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFormatFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, HtmlStringFormatter formatter)
        {
            var output = helper.DisplayFor(expression);
            string formatted = formatter.Delegate.Invoke(output.ToString());
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(formatted);
        }
    }
}

namespace MvcPlay.HtmlStringFormatting
{
    public class HtmlStringFormatter
    {
        public delegate string FormatDelegate(string s);

        public FormatDelegate Delegate;
        public Expression<FormatDelegate> formatExpression;

        private HtmlStringFormatter(FormatDelegate expression)
        {
            Delegate = expression;
        }

        protected HtmlStringFormatter()
        {

        }

        public static HtmlStringFormatter Create(FormatDelegate expression)
        {
            return new HtmlStringFormatter(expression);
        }
    }

    public class CapitalLetterFormatter : HtmlStringFormatter
    {
        public CapitalLetterFormatter()
        {
            Delegate =
                s => new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the following lines to the Web.Config at the Views folder:

```
<add namespace="MvcPlay.HelperExtensions" />
<add namespace="MvcPlay.HtmlStringFormatting"/>
```

This will include the Formatters and the Helper Extension automatically so you won't need to include it inside every view that you want to use it in.